# Is there any curriculum based on recreational mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, education

I'm a high school physics teacher. Next year, I'll be teaching mathematics for middle school students so I was wondering if there's a curriculum based on [recreational mathematics](http://anduin.eldar.org/~problemi/singmast/ecmutil.html)  which not only present a sequence of puzzles and games but which also should have definite objectives. I hope there's such curricula because if not I'll have to make such one and it will take a really long time to author and test.

Comment: Isn't it more or less the definition of recreational mathematics that it *isn't* the kind of thing you find in formal curricula?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Recreational mathematics include the kind of problems that are simple to understand and interesting and at the same time have an easy or at most intermediate solution (relative to the person). For example, you can use the [ant on a rubber rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope) to introduce the harmonic series or as an interesting ODE; another puzzle is the [tower of hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi).

Comment: What are the legally mandated topics? How much freedom do you have in choice of course material?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have some topics to explain like the Pythagorean theorem, square roots, expansion and factorization...but I don't want to do them the boring way (write the statements on the board and explain them), I want the students to be more interested.

Comment: I understand that. I also know, however, that in many school systems the individual teacher has relatively little freedom to modify the curriculum, and I wondered under what restrictions you would be operating.

Comment: I can do whatever I want, the important thing is that, at the end of a chapter. the students should be able to solve the exercises and even better if they liked the chapter. Why do you think students like combinatorial problems more than complex numbers or calculus.

Comment: If you are still interested in this (I'm writing a year after you asked your question), I recommend looking at the "math appreciation" books I mentioned in [this comment](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/alternative-remedial-courses-before-calculus#comment5659_2575).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Unfortunately I didn't find this book online but I have some of Martin Gardener's books. Since there isn't any curriculum built completely on recreational mathematics, I'm trying to write a book for high school students. It will be a combination of rigor, fun, puzzles and simple explanations. I just begun with it, I wrote the ToC, you can see it [here](http://www.elienasrallah.com/bibliography/ME.pdf). I hope I can finish it in the following 2 years.

Comment: The contents sound interesting. However, it doesn't look like recreational mathematics for middle school students to me (in the U.S. this typically means before any school algebra, such as percents and negative numbers and very basic geometry, etc.), but rather it looks like a mid-level undergraduate "transition to advanced mathematics" text. In any event, for recreational mathematics you will find a lot of references in [David Singmaster's various on-line lists](http://anduin.eldar.org/~problemi/singmast/).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro As I mentioned, it's for high school. It contains the Lebanese curriculum+ some extra sections marked by $\dagger$. I hope I can include a large amount of recreational mathematics in the examples and exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a number of such books, though I wouldn't call it a "curriculum".  I suggest you try the recent books by [Ian Stewart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Stewart_%28mathematician%29), particularly Professor Stewart's Cabinet of Mathematical Curiosities (2008)
and Professor Stewart's Hoard of Mathematical Treasures: Another Drawer from the Cabinet of Curiosities (2009).

Comment: I have many of these books; they are interesting but I was looking for a *curriculum* based on recreational mathematics. **Note:** Any interesting (simple) problem of combinatorics, probability, number theory, graph theory... could be considered as recreational.